# PHP MYSQL get column based on date month

Tags: php, mysql

I don't even know how to ask this question...

So there is a database in place in which the columns are the months of the year:

`January | February | March`

Then each column has it's values:

```
jan1   | feb1   | mar1

jan2 | feb 2 | mar2

jan3 | feb3 | mar3
```

Sorry, I didn't know how to insert a table in Stack Overflow.

So when I run a query, I was wondering if there was a way mysql can automatically identify the current month, and use that to select the corresponding column.

So if the current month is January, then the SELECT would look like this:

```
 $select = "SELECT UID, JANUARY FROM table WHERE UID = '1'";
```

That would bring back the column data for January where the UID = 1.

But when it's February, the query needs to automatically adjust the SELECT statement to select February.

I am not even sure if this is possible.  I just wanted to see if anyone might know if there is a way to do this.

Comment: It is a bad choice to put months as columns. It should un-pivotted to have 12 as many rows, with an extra key column with the month number.

Comment: `select date_format(now(), '%M') as cur_month`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a pure SQL solution, go for this:

```
select  uid,
        case month(curdate())
            when 1 then january
            when 2 then february
            when 3 then march
            when 4 then april
            when 5 then may
            when 6 then june
            when 7 then july
            when 8 then august
            when 9 then september
            when 10 then october
            when 11 then november
            when 12 then december
        end as month_data
from    mytable
where   uid = '1';
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01ff0/1).

Comment: All of the responses were good and better than what I expected.  I expected to get bashed but this turned into a good post.  I went with your answer and it worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use PHP built-in date() function, specified [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
date("F")  // returns full string representation of current month like "January"
```

The code would then look something like this:

```
$select = "SELECT UID, ".date("F")." FROM table WHERE UID = '1'";
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has no function similar to eval(), so you have to include some long code like @trincot's answer. But if you don't mind using a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) it can be done in a clearer way (IMHO):

```
set @s = CONCAT('SELECT ', MONTHNAME(NOW()), ' FROM meses');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```